# A finite set of points in R2 as a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is probably a *very* basic question, but I'm new to the field (no pun intended) of algebraic geometry, and I'm trying to understand why a set of points in R^2 is sometimes provided as an example when discussing fields. For example:

> "Consider a field F, and finite set of points S in F^n... For example,
>   consider the points (j, 2^j) in R^2 with j = {1,...,10^6} ...."

Why is this a valid example if R^2 is not a field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do say "finite set of points S in F^n", not "finite set of points S in F".

$\Bbb R$ is a field, and $(j, j^2)$ for $j\in \{1, \ldots, 10^{16}\}$ is a finite set of points in $\Bbb R^n$ for $n = 2$.